# Intercept append method on dom

Tags: javascript, html, dom, jquery

i need a way to parsing the dynamic content of webpage.
For example if I need to append a class for every element with a class "test" i can do like that :

```
$(".test").each(function(index, element)
{
    if(!$(this).data("parsed"))
    {
        $(this).data("parsed", true);
        //all my operation - Example :
        $(this).addClass("new-class");
    }
});
```

That work, but only for the html at this time.
If on second time I append new html to my page, that will not parsed by my script.
I would a way for do that.
There is a method called when the content change? For example on every append, html, ajax request etc?

Answer (score 0):

That could be one own solution :

```
var original_append = $.fn.append;
$.fn.append = function()
{
    console.log(arguments);
    //my code
    return original_append.apply(this, arguments);
}
```